# Which is my identicon?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, gravatar, user-profile

I’m confused about my identicon.

When I’m using iOS app, it’s a green one; however, on the website I get a blue purple one.....Could anyone tell me why? Thanks!

**PS**: I now can see I have that blue one in this MSE meta community.....even if I’m using my app.....

Comment: I believe it is assigned by Gravatar ( https://en.gravatar.com ) using your information.  Perhaps your email address.  If you like, you can paste in a picture of your own, rather than using theirs.  So somehow, your information when you first logged in on iOS was different from your information when you first logged in on your computer.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks! It helps me a lot!

Comment: There's something weird with your math.SE account.  If I look at your profile (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/517681/benny) you have a green icon but if I look at your posts, you have a blue icon.  Across the rest of the network you have a blue icon, it's just this one place.

Comment: @BrianNickel Thanks for your comment！I'm also confused about that.

Comment: @BrianNickel And when I myself see my posts using app, I have the green icon; whereas using website, the blue one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next builds.

You were experiencing a bug that affects Gravatar/Identicon users who have capital letters in their email address.  Because we request icons of various sizes, we build Gravatar requests on demand using various data including email addresses.  The algorithm we're supposed to use is `MD5(ToLower(email) + salt)` but our code was missing the `ToLower`.

So, why were you getting different icons different places?  Because when we fetch a batch of users and convert them to objects, a hook converts them to lower case, but when we fetch a single user it doesn't.  The API fetches batches of users with different code that also doesn't have that hook.

Now the algorithm correctly lower cases the string and you'll start being bluish purple everywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I do prefer the green one (; ω ;)